# How to round off a string and integer in python

Tags: python

Good day,
I have a list of ICD 10 Codes example is U07.01, Z152.8154, X98.23 etc.. they are provided by WHO

I want to round off this to be U07.0, Z152.8, X98.2 in Odoo, I have tried to use the in built in round but is it giving an error.
Here is my code....

```
code.text = round(str(patient_line.doc_disease_id.code).lower(), 1) or ' '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `str slicing`.
For example:

```
l = ['U07.01', 'Z152.8154', 'X98.23']
new_list = []
for i in l:
    first_part, second_part = str(i).split('.')
    second_part = second_part[:1]

    new = f'{first_part}.{second_part}'
    new_list.append(new)

print(new_list)
```

for only one code at a time as **OP wanted**:

```
first_part, second_part = str(old_code).split('.')
second_part = second_part[:1]

new = f'{first_part}.{second_part}'
print(new)
```

Comment: Thanks 
But i am new to Python and I only have one code at a time not a list
I have tried the code below and it is giving an error






"""""""""""""""""""""""
oldcode = "Z152.8154"

                    new_code = ''
                    for i in oldcode:
                        first_part, second_part = str(i).split('.')
                        second_part = second_part[:1]

                        new = f'{first_part}.{second_part}'
                        new_code.append(new)   
                    code.text = str(new_list).lower() or ' '

Comment: if there is only one code at a time;  Then you don't do do the loop. you can use directly `first_part, second_part = str(oldcode).split('.')`.  please check the updated answer